# TCP checksum error for fragmented packets

Tags: tcp, ip, checksum, ip-fragmentation

I'm working on a server/client socket application that is using Linux TUN interface.

Server gets packets directly from TUN interface and pass them to clients and clients put received packets directly in the TUN interface.

```
<Server_TUN---><---Server---><---Clients---><---Client_TUN--->
```

Sometimes the packets from Server_TUN need to be fragmented in IP layer before transmitting to a client.

So at the server I read a packet from TUN, start fragmenting it in the IP layer and send them via socket to clients.

When the fragmentation logic was implemented, the solution did not work well.

After starting Wireshark on Client_TUN I noticed for all incoming fragmented packets I get TCP Checksum error.

[image: wireshark capture]

At the given screenshot, frame number 154 is claimed to be reassembled in in 155.

But TCP checksum is claimed to be incorrect!

At server side, I keep tcp data intact and for the given example, while you see the reverse in Wireshark, I've split a packet with 1452 bytes (including IP header) and 30 bytes (Including IP header)

I've also checked the TCP checksum value at the server and its exactly is 0x935e and while I did not think that Checksum offloading matters for incoming packets, I checked offloading at the client and it was off.

```
$ sudo ethtool -k tun0 | grep ": on"
scatter-gather: on
tx-scatter-gather: on
tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: on
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: on
```

Despite that, because of the solution is not working now, I don't think its caused by offload effect.

Do you have any idea why TCP checksum could be incorrect for fragmented packets?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I found the issue. It was my mistake. Some tcp data was missing when I was coping buffers. I was tracing on the indexes and lengths but because of the changes in data, checksum value was calculating differently in the client side.